# RPC call on bitcoind for adding P2SH

Tags: bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

I have been searching around a lot and I can't seem to figure this out.

I want to create a transaction with a custom *P2SH* address by using *Bitcoin Core's* RPC calls. I found there is a `redeemScript` field in `signrawtransaction` so I'm assuming this is where I should send a hex encoding of my script. But this needs a `txid`, so should I first use `createrawtransaction` with the output being the address I want to send to and then sign the transaction with the script included?

I saw there is already a `createmultisig` call and since that is also *P2SH* it seems there should be something similar for other *P2SH* transactions.

Any idea how I can solve this or where I can find more information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly according to [this](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch07.asciidoc#p2sh-addresses) section of the bitcoin book, you are supposed to create a hash out of your script and then convert  this hash into an address which allows you to use the regular `sendtoaddress` rpc call to send coins to the address.

> Another important part of the P2SH feature is the ability to encode a script hash as an address, as defined in BIP-13. P2SH addresses are Base58Check encodings of the 20-byte hash of a script, just like bitcoin addresses are Base58Check encodings of the 20-byte hash of a public key. P2SH addresses use the version prefix "5," which results in Base58Check-encoded addresses that start with a "3."
>
> Now, Mohammed can give this "address" to his customers and they can use almost any bitcoin wallet to make a simple payment, as if it were a bitcoin address. The 3 prefix gives them a hint that this is a special type of address, one corresponding to a script instead of a public key, but otherwise it works in exactly the same way as a payment to a bitcoin address.
>
> P2SH addresses hide all of the complexity, so that the person making a payment does not see the script.

Take a look at the whole [section](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch07.asciidoc#pay-to-script-hash-p2sh) for how to convert the script to a hash.

You can download the executable that is used in the book here: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/releases

Comment: Thanks. Yep, this is the way to go. I found some other resource on the bitcoin developer guide where they show a good example with multisig p2sh: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#p2sh-multisig